# SQLite to SQL and Back Sync - Use of PrimaryKey Problem

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sqlite, synchronization

I have SQL database in remote place as primary database.

User, however initially stores data to local SQLite. I have code that synchronizes records between SQLite and SQL.

As the SQL DB is primary, I set the ID as PrimaryKey for identity. In SQLite initially I did not set primarykey on ID, because this will mess up my records.

When user creates record, it is stored in local db without id. Upon SYNC initiated, SQL is looked up whether record with matching ID and Name exist.

If false(as local db record does not have any ID yet) the local record is uploaded to SQL and PrimaryKey is assigned. Then, ID generated is passed back to the SQLite and assigned to the record.

From this moment, not earlier, the local db record has an ID and further transactions are made by using the ID.

This is how I perform sync between local db and SQL. Basically I couldn't think of better way for sync between the two DB's. Maybe I'm wrong, but it's actually first time I attempt such operation.

Is it good approach?

Or should I assign the PrimaryKey ID to local db records too?

Comment: Do your tables have a candidate natural key?  If they do, consider using that for at least the initial sync.

Comment: What would be the purpose of using such I'd?

Comment: In my environment I treat Name column as initial ID in sqlite. I do not allow multiple records with same Name in SQL.